# BufWritePost chaining commands

Tags: neovim

What is wrong in my init.vim / vim.rc config setup?

Error:

> Error detected while processing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*.py":
>
> E488: Trailing characters: :silent PyrightOrganizeImports:silent !yapf -i -q %

the config in my init.vim / vim.rc is:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.py :silent PyrightOrganizeImports<cr>:silent !yapf -i -q %
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no such thing as `vim.rc`. Vim's main config file is called `vimrc`.
2. The right-hand-side of an autocommand is not a normal mode command. It is an Ex command, where `<CR>` has no meaning.

   In order to execute two Ex commands in sequence, you must do like in the command-line: separate them with a pipe character:

   ```
   autocmd BufWritePost *.py :silent PyrightOrganizeImports|silent !yapf -i -q %
   ```

   Note that the first command must have been defined with the `-bar` flag.

Comment: Apologies. I'm using NeoVim 0.5 and it has init.vim. I tried your config but i'm still getting the same E488 error - what do you mean by the -bar flag? It works as separate commands but i'm unable to chain them

Comment: If you don't use Vim then there is no point mentioning or tagging it.